# NPE during navigation with viewscoped bean using Mojarra 2.2.x with openwebbeans 1.0 (CDI 1.0)

Tags: cdi, jsf-2.2, mojarra, view-scope, openwebbeans

I am now running into a ViewScope issue on h:commandButton with navigation. 
I am not sure if JSF 2.2 is supported with CDI 1.0

Error

```
May 28, 2020 5:57:07 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl throwIt
INFO: Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeContextManager.destroyBeans(ViewScopeContextManager.java:171)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeContextManager.clear(ViewScopeContextManager.java:122)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeManager.processPreDestroyViewMap(ViewScopeManager.java:335)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeManager.processEvent(ViewScopeManager.java:240)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeEventListener.processEvent(ViewScopeEventListener.java:68)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
    at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.processListener(ComponentSystemEvent.java:118)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2142)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot$ViewMap.clear(UIViewRoot.java:1850)
    at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.clearViewMapIfNecessary(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:432)
    at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.handleNavigation(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.handleNavigation(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:183)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:132)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

[**Minimal, Reproducible Example in a Tomcat 8.5 environment**](https://github.com/ravihariharan/was8555/tree/master/mojarra_openwebbeans)
*test.xhtml -> "ajax working" button works , "h:commandButton non-ajax" button fails*

1. Fails with Mojarra version jsf-api-2.2.13 & jsf-impl-2.2.13
2. Fails with Mojarra version javax.faces-2.2.20
3. Works with myfaces version myfaces-api-2.2.12 and myfaces-impl-2.2.12
4. Works with omnifaces version omnifaces-1.8.3 org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped (addition jar validation-api-1.1.0.Final was required to be added)

**TestView.java**

```
package com.lean.demo;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestView implements Serializable {

    public String goNextCase1() {
        System.out.println("goNextCase1");
        // Add navigation-case with <redirect />
        return "PageTestView2";
    }

    public String goNextCase2() {
        System.out.println("goNextCase2");
        return "test2.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String goNextCase3() {
        System.out.println("goNextCase3");
        return "test2.xhtml";
    }
}
```

**test.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <title>Mojarra JSF 2.2 with openwebbeans 1.1.0 (CDI 1.0)</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form id="frmTest">
        <h2>
            <h:commandButton value="Case 1" action="#{testView.goNextCase1()}">
            </h:commandButton>
        </h2>
        <h2>
            <h:commandButton value="Case 2" action="#{testView.goNextCase2()}">
            </h:commandButton>
        </h2>
        <h2>
            <h:commandButton value="Case 3" action="#{testView.goNextCase3()}">
            </h:commandButton>
        </h2>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**Jars in Lib**

```
commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar
commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec-1.0.jar
geronimo-interceptor_1.1_spec-1.0.jar
geronimo-jcdi_1.0_spec-1.0.jar
javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
jsf-api-2.2.13.jar
jsf-impl-2.2.13.jar
openwebbeans-impl-1.1.0.jar
openwebbeans-jsf-1.1.0.jar
openwebbeans-resource-1.1.0.jar
openwebbeans-spi-1.1.0.jar
openwebbeans-web-1.1.0.jar
scannotation-1.0.2.jar
```

Comment: 1: [mcve]'s should be posted inline, 2: Try to bundle all in the war like on Tomcat, better approach imo than using the shared librarie solution. So you can include cdi 1.2 as well  3: Make sure the one forcing you to downgraded gets fired ;-)

Comment: @Kukeltje the example tries to replicate the WAS 8.5.5 issue on tomcat.  The issue is the customer is a DMZ / enclave that has WAS 8.5.5. customer would like to move out of WAS into kubernetes based setup in near future (near for customer is 2-3 years lol) and in the interim they do not want to move to WAS 9

Comment: same error with h:commandButton

Comment: it works with ajax.

Comment: You're going to see problems if your intention is to us JSF 2.2 along with the CDI implementation provided by WAS 8.5.5: there is no integration between the WAS-provided CDI and user-provided JSF implementations. See stackoverflow.com/a/32633551/…

Comment: @wtlucy so far i have only see 1 issue of non-ajax button navigation that fails in mojarra. it works for myfaces OR when i change ViewScope to omnifaces. My test tries to mimic WAS setup on tomcat for CDI i.e. openwebbeans 1.1.0

Comment: @Kukeltje In my example CDI works with mojarra 2.2.13 with openwebbeans 1.1.0 (currently testing on tomcat). The issue is non-ajax  button request fails only in Mojarra in ViewScope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215538/discussion-between-kukeltje-and-ravi).